# write double into a file

Tags: java, file, char, double, typeconverter

How can I convert a double into a const char, and then convert it back into a double? I  want to convert the double to a string, to write it to a file  and then when I read the file, it  needed to be converted back into a double

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double.toString()

Double.parseDouble(String s)

Comment: @Joey This will have the same precision that `double` has.  If there are extra digits in the string which cannot be represented they will be discarded.  If this is an issue, I would use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

Making Double as constant

```
public final Double DOUBLE = 20D;
```

making double as String -

```
String.valueOf(DOUBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

double x = 3.14159;
Any basic datatype can easily be converted to String by concatenating them with a String even if it is ""
String value = "" + x;
Most datatype Object counterpart have a parseXXX() method to translate a String into that datatype
double y = Double.parseDouble(value);

Answer (score -1):

You can directly invoke the "write" method to a double. 
For instance:

```
double testDouble = 2.0;
bufferedOut.write(testDouble);
```

Then when reading the file as a string you can do the following to convert back to double:

```
String line = //<what you read from file>;
double gotDouble = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

Comment: you are wrong! before i already tried it and its not working! i mean for the first line

Comment: your first line, i already tested, before i post this question